# DataTables warning: table id=products - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, datatables

I am getting this error when i run the script "127.0.0.1:60809 says DataTables warning: table id=products - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7"

[the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4Mft.png)

I am using HTML and mysql. This error happens to show when i click on anything in the data table. For instance if i click on the search box, the error message i mentioned above pops out. I hope anyone can help me out with this. Thank you in advance.

**This is the code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#products').DataTable({
      'processing': true,
      'serverSide': true,
      'serverMethod': 'post',
      'ajax': {
          'url':'read.php',
      },
      'columns': [
         { data: 'id' },
         { data: 'name' },
         { data: 'description' },
         { data: 'price' },
         { data: 'category_id' },
         { data: 'category_name' },
         { data: 'created' },
         { data: 'modified' },
      ]
   });
});
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What about checking in your browser's developer console whether there is any AJAX problem?

Comment: the status code is showing 405 method not allowed whereas whn i click on preview its showing this error "{code: "MethodNotAllowedError", message: "POST is not allowed"}". read.php is highlighted in red

Comment: And what have you tried to check further why this is happening?

Comment: further i found out that whenever i change the serverMethod: from post to fetch, the error stops showing but when i click on the table nothing works. I cant search or sort the table. is the problem regarding my serverMethod or is there anything got to do with my .php file?

Comment: This is my js code :

_italic_ **bold** `<script type="text/javascript">  
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#products').DataTable({
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "serverMethod": "FETCH",
      "ajax": {
          "url":"read.php",
    
      },
      'columns': [
         { data: 'id' },
         { data: 'name' },
         { data: 'description' },
         { data: 'price' },
         { data: 'category_id' },
         { data: 'category_name' },
         { data: 'created' },
         { data: 'modified' },
      ]
   });
});`

Comment: Edit your question to add these new findings, instead of adding them in comments. If you are asking a question about your PHP file, then add that code to the question also.

Comment: I have never seen `'serverMethod': '<value>'` before - I can't even find any documentation about it in the DataTables web site. I found something similar - [`sServerMethod`](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert#Options) for an older version of the DataTables Editor. It's more normal to see `"ajax": {"type": "POST/GET", ...}`.

Comment: Sure @andrewjames.. i am kinda new here.. sorry for the inconvenience.. I am currently following this tutorial [link](https://makitweb.com/datatables-ajax-pagination-with-search-and-sort-php/). to create the datatable. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Compare that tutorial with [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side) froDataTables web site. I would copy & adapt the DataTables web site example first, get it working, and then go from there. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

i finally figured out the solution by my own. The solution is to just add these lines of codes

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#your table name').DataTable();

 });
```

and boom.. it worked. i hope this solution would help you!